# FluentMigrator default value set to another column's value

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I am trying to set the default value to another column's current value. Is there any way to do this easily with FluentMigrator ?

```
public override void Up()
{
    Alter.Table(NomTable.VenteMetadata).AddColumn("Column").AsString()
    .NotNullable().WithDefaultValue("??");
}

public override void Down()
{
    Delete.Column("Column").FromTable(NomTable.VenteMetadata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that using `WithDefaultValue`. You could create an insert trigger to achieve what you want if you are using Microsoft SQL Server:

```
Execute.Sql(@"
    CREATE TRIGGER VenteMetadata_AfterInsert_TRG 
    ON VenteMetadata 
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    UPDATE VenteMetadata t
    SET t.Column = t.OtherColumn
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE t.Id = i.Id
");
```